# How to select rows in TIMESTAMP column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
col1
-------------
22/01/15 16:45:05,657432556
21/12/22 11:01:33,234543456
21/10/13 10:15:45,437483674
21/11/12 11:22:01,315432223
```

Above column "col1" is as TIMESTAMP and I would like to

- 1. select only these dates between 21/10/01 and 21/12/01
- 2. create new column "col2" with converted TIMESTAMP to date

So as a result I would like to have something like below:

```
col1                        | col2
----------------------------------------
21/10/13 10:15:45,437483674 | 21/10/13
21/11/12 11:22:01,315432223 | 21/11/12
```

How can I do that in Oracle SQL ?

Comment: First part is a simple range check. For second part do you actually mean a date, or a string with the date part in that format (2-digit years?); and a 'new column' in the table, or just as part of a query?

Comment: Yes, 'new column' in the table :)

Comment: Do you want to include *before* 2021-12-01 00:00:00.0, *including* exactly 2021-12-01 00:00:00.0 but nothing later that day, or everything that day? (I would assume *before* but 'between' is a bit ambiguous...). And you haven't really said if col2 should be a date or a string; and if a date, if it should keep the time.

Comment: _"Yes, 'new column' in the table :)"_   Bad idea. Never store a value that can be derived from another value.  It is only a matter of time before they get out of sync.  If the value of COL_B is derived from COL_A, then do it when you select the data. Don't try to store it in the table.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you can add a virtual column - so you don't have to maintain both values - which converts the timestamp to a date, either preserving the time part:

```
alter table your_table add (col2 date generated always as (cast(col1 as date)));
```

```
COL1                        COL2
--------------------------  -------------------
2022-01-15 16:45:05.657432  2022-01-15 16:45:05
2021-12-22 11:01:33.234543  2021-12-22 11:01:33
2021-10-13 10:15:45.437483  2021-10-13 10:15:45
2021-11-12 11:22:01.315432  2021-11-12 11:22:01
```

or truncating to midnight:

```
alter table your_table add (col2 date generated always as (trunc(cast(col1 as date))));
```

```
COL1                        COL2
--------------------------  -------------------
2022-01-15 16:45:05.657432  2022-01-15 00:00:00
2021-12-22 11:01:33.234543  2021-12-22 00:00:00
2021-10-13 10:15:45.437483  2021-10-13 00:00:00
2021-11-12 11:22:01.315432  2021-11-12 00:00:00
```

To restrict the dates, you need to determine what 'between' means to you. As you're using the first day of the month I would *assume* you really want all data in October and November, with nothing actually from December 1st; in which case:

```
select * from your_table
where col1 >= timestamp '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
and col2 < timestamp '2021-12-01 00:00:00'
```

```
COL1                        COL2
--------------------------  -------------------
2021-10-13 10:15:45.437483  2021-10-13 00:00:00
2021-11-12 11:22:01.315432  2021-11-12 00:00:00
```

If you want to include exactly midnight on the first then make that `<=`. To include the whole of that day make is `<` midnight on the 2nd.

If you want the results in a specific output format then change your client/session settings, or explicitly convert to strings (for display only):

```
select to_char(col1, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9') as col1,
  to_char(col2, 'YY/MM/DD') as col2
from your_table
where col1 >= timestamp '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
and col2 < timestamp '2021-12-01 00:00:00'
```

```
COL1                         COL2
---------------------------  --------
21/10/13 10:15:45,437483674  21/10/13
21/11/12 11:22:01,315432223  21/11/12
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56a4c5abb14034d8b4d6fe3e466e4a8e)

Answer (score 0):

Table contents:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               TIMESTAMP(6)
 COL2                                               DATE

SQL> select * From test order by col1;

COL1                           COL2
------------------------------ -------------------
13.10.21 10:15:45,437484
22.12.21 11:01:33,234543
15.01.22 16:45:05,657433
15.01.22 16:45:05,657433

SQL>
```

**For 1**, one option is to use a timestamp literal:

```
SQL> select * From test where col1 between timestamp '2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'
  2                                    and timestamp '2021-12-01 00:00:00.000';

COL1                           COL2
------------------------------ -------------------
13.10.21 10:15:45,437484

SQL>
```

**For 2**, use `CAST`:

```
SQL> update test set col2 = cast (col1 as date);

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test order by col1;

COL1                           COL2
------------------------------ -------------------
13.10.21 10:15:45,437484       13.10.2021 10:15:45
22.12.21 11:01:33,234543       22.12.2021 11:01:33
15.01.22 16:45:05,657433       15.01.2022 16:45:05
15.01.22 16:45:05,657433       15.01.2022 16:45:05

SQL>
```